# Couldn't set the cookie using the fetch function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

My express server is running on port 3001.

IN THE REACT FILE

On my login page.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/login',{
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(this.state),
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        mode:'cors'
    }).then((respo)=>{
        console.log(respo);
    })
```

on the home page

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/home',{credentials:'same-origin'}).then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then((response)=>{
        this.setState({
            isLoading:false,
            userData:response.user,
            posts:response.posts
        })
    })
```

when i set my cookie on the login page, From the dev tools I could see my cookie is being set . But i don't receive the set-Cookie on the home page. Where i am going wrong here?

EDIT: setting the cookie (server side)

```
    const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sessions = require('client-sessions');
const Post = require('./model/post');
const User = require('./model/user');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/social_network',{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useCreateIndex:true
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors({
    origin:"http://127.0.0.1:3000"
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    })
  );

app.use(sessions({
    cookieName:'users',
    secret:'ouououou',
    duration: 24*60*60*60
}))

const auth= async(req,res,next)=>{
    try{
        console.log(req.users.user);
        const user = await User.findOne({email:req.users.email,password:req.users.password});
        if(!user){
            throw new Error("No User Found");
        }else{
            next();
        }
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        res.status(404).send({error:e});
    }

}

app.post("/api/login",async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        console.log(req.body.email);
        const user = await 
User.findOne({email:req.body.email,password:req.body.password});
        if(!user){
            throw new Error("User Not Found");
        }else{
            req.users.user = user;
            console.log(req.users.user);
            res.status(200).send(req.user);
        }
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        res.status(404).send({error:e})
    }
})


app.get('/api/home',auth,async (req,res)=>{
    console.log("yo");
    await req.user.populate('post').execPopulate();
    const data={user:user,post:user.post}
    res.send(data)
    });


app.listen("3001",()=>{
    console.log("on");
});
```

Comment: where is your code to set the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Your API server is `localhost:3001`.

Your page is loaded from `127.0.0.1:3000`

These are **different origins**.

You said `credentials: 'same-origin'` so cross-origin credentials, including cookies, are disabled.

You need `include` to send cookies for cross-origin calls.

See also: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials).

Comment: I have tried hosting my server on localhost:3001 but the result stays the same. When I change my credentials to include then there are cors problems.

Comment: ERROR  :       `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/api/login' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

Comment: @AniketTyagi so change the configuration you pass to `cors()` to enable that. The documentation for that module is pretty good.